# Running Time Complexity of Any Block of Code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, calculation

We can easily find Big-O of any code and there is a lot of resources to understand how to calculate Big-O, but I wanted to understand how can we calculate Big-O of any code with non-dominant term. For example, let's talk about this code:

```
Statement 1;
for i=0 to n:
  for j=0 to m
     Statement 2;
  End for
End for
```

In this pseudo code, Big-O is O(n^2) but I want to calculate T(n) with non-dominant term.
Here's my answer:

```
Statement 1;               1
    for i=0 to n:          n+2
      for j=0 to m         n(m+2)
         Statement 2;      n(m+1) 
      End for            
    End for
```

T(n) = 1+n+2+n(m+2)+n(m+1)
= 2n^2 + 4n + 3     since m = n;

Can anyone correct this if I'm wrong. Also, please share some resources where I can read about this.

Comment: Looks good to me, but in most cases it's not so easy. `if`-statements loops loops-boundaries that depend on other loop-variables ...

Comment: you perform `n +1` times `m +1` times Statement2, or so you do it `(n + 1) * (m + 1) = n * m + m + n + 1` times. since *both* `n` and `m` are *large* (`n >> 1` and `m >> 1`), `n * m + m + n + 1 ~ n * m` or put it in other words `O(n * m)` in general case. When `n ~ m` we can put it simply as `O(n^2)`